# Why is Ajax request slower than visiting the URL in the browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, time, response

I have a server that provides data via a given URL. If I use Ajax to retrieve the data, it takes somewhere around 300 to 400 milliseconds according to the Network tab in Chrome. If I visit the same URL by typing it into the address bar, it takes somewhere around 100 to 150 milliseconds according to the Network panel.

Why is the request so much slower when requested via Ajax?

I looked into some possibilities such as domain limits on the number of connections to a given domain, but this request is the only request being made to that domain at that time. There are many other requests (to different domains) being made at the same time, could they be slowing this specific request down? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Edit: It seems like there are actually two delays. I did some more testing by logging the timestamp before the ajax request and after it completed. Sometimes the time measured this way is very different from the time of the request according to the network panel. This is the second delay. For example, in once instance, the time measured with the timestamps was 190 milliseconds more than the request measured in the network panel. Other times the timestamp measure is just a few milliseconds longer than the network panel. Is this just an issue with the browser tools being unable to accurately measure?

Comment: It probably isn't actually slower.  Use a packet sniffer to verify.  Don't trust such small timings in your developer tools.  Page load can affect your developer tools timings.

Comment: The Chrome network tab *may* not be the best tool for job here. You aren't necessarily comparing like with like. See if you get the same results with a tool like fiddler.

Comment: @Jon  It has been consistent in the browser network panel (for whatever that's worth). I know the request is taking more than 150 milliseconds because if it was returned in less than 150 there would be an effect on the page (the page effect has a timeout such that it will not wait more than 150 milliseconds for the ajax response. Once that timeout elapses it will ignore the ajax response, even if it is received). I'll look into Linux alternatives for Fiddler to verify the times though.

Comment: Have you confirmed the response for visiting URL is not from Cache?

Comment: @Ramesh Yes. I have cache disabled via the DevTools settings in chrome (disable cache while DevTools is open).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Latency Calculation by AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221266/latency-calculation-by-ajax)